# Obtener el dato de lectura del sensor GPS cada 5 segundos

Tags: python, hilos, gps, raspberry-pi

Estoy usando el sensor de GPS NEO y obtengo correctamente las coordenadas, quiero capturar la cordenada de lectura cada 5 segundos. Como mencioné, logro haver la lectura pero no la captura cada 5 segudnos, mi programa es el siguiente:

```
import gps
import itertools
import json
import os
import portdetect
import time
import serial
from threading import Thread

(puerto1, puerto2) = portdetect.detectar_puerto()
print puerto1, puerto2
port = serial.Serial(puerto1, 115200, timeout=1)

os.system('sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket')
time.sleep(2)
os.system('sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket')
time.sleep(2)
comando = 'sudo gpsd ' + puerto2 + ' -F /var/run/gpsd.sock'
os.system(str(comando))
#print str(comando)

# Listen on port 2947 (gpsd) of localhost
session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
session.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

class Contador:
    def __init__(self, comienzo = 0):
        self.raw_datos = comienzo

def leergps(self):
    while True:
        try:
            report = session.next()
            # Wait for a 'TPV' report and display the current time
            # To see all report data, uncomment the line below
            # print report
            if report['class'] == 'TPV':
                if hasattr(report, 'time') or hasattr(report, 'lat') or hasattr(report, 'lon') or hasattr(report,
                                                                                                          'speed'):
                    datos = [report.time, report.lat, report.lon, report.speed]
                    clave = ['tiempo', 'lat', 'lon', 'speed']
                    diccionario = dict(itertools.izip(clave, datos))
                    self.raw_datos = (json.dumps(diccionario))
                # print raw_datos
                return self.raw_datos
            else:
                return report['class']
        except:
            print "Error de coordenadas"

def capturar(self):
    while True:
        posicion = self.raw_datos
        time.sleep(5)
        print posicion


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Contador()
    Thread(target = c.capturar).start()
    Thread(target = c.leergps()).start()
```

cuando corro el programa, me manda solo "0".

Alguna idea que me pudan orientar?

Comment: `target = c.leergps()` no es correcto , debe ser `Thread(target = c.leergps).start()`, al llamar al método le estas pasando el retorno de `c.leergps` no la referencia al método.

Comment: Por cierto, los `return` en la función de lectura hacen que solo se lean los datos una vez, cualquier `return` hace que la función termine y con ella el ciclo infinito y el hilo. Esa `while True` está condenado a iterar una sola vez, no se si es lo que quieres, pero de serlo el ciclo sobra y si no es lo que deseas los `return` sobran.